# Cocos2d 2.x Orientation issues with Kamcord framework

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, orientation

I am using latest cocos2d 2.x with latest Kamcord version.

My application is in portrait mode, but I have some scenes where I use landscape mode by just rotating the portrait to 90 degrees.

My application is built for portrait only mode. I want to take the video of landscape screen, but when I share it on facebook/email it appears at 90 degrees to line of view.

Can I tell Kamcord where to take video in portrait mode and where to take in landscape mode, irrespective of my application orientation?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `glRotate` to rotate your OpenGL view? If so, then Kamcord won't know about your rotation. You can also email us directly at support@kamcord.com with your setup.

Comment: rotating the entire scene with scene.rotate